# Error message displayed when python starts

Tags: python

I recently did

```
pip install --user sphinx-toolbox
```

Since then i get the following error message each time i run a python script:

```
Error processing line 1 of /home/jody/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_sphinx_jinja2_compat.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python-exec/python3.9/../../../lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/home/jody/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sphinx_jinja2_compat/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
      import markupsafe  # noqa: E402
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'markupsafe'

Remainder of file ignored
```

After this my scripts works normally.

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried `pip install markupsafe`?

Comment: When i run this command, i get ``Requirement already satisfied: markupsafe in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.1.1)``